# Brillo's partitioning scheme

Tags: android, linux, android-things, disk-partitioning, brillo

I've just recently stumbled over Brillo on Google's source code website. On it, I've found several files with the extension `bpt`. These are JSON files that appear to describe partitions on devices. [Here](https://android.googlesource.com/device/generic/brillo/+/master/brillo_partitions.bpt) are the contents of the base file:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "disk_size": "4 GiB"
    },
    "partitions": [
        {
            "ab": true,
            "label": "boot",
            "size": "32 MiB",
            "guid": "auto",
            "type_guid": "brillo_boot"
        },
        {
            "ab": true,
            "label": "system",
            "size": "512 MiB",
            "guid": "auto",
            "type_guid": "brillo_system"
        },
        {
            "ab": true,
            "label": "odm",
            "size": "512 MiB",
            "guid": "auto",
            "type_guid": "brillo_odm"
        },
        {
            "label": "misc",
            "size": "1 MiB",
            "type_guid": "brillo_misc"
        },
        {
            "label": "userdata",
            "grow": true,
            "guid": "auto",
            "type_guid": "brillo_userdata"
        }
    ]
}
```

I can't find any documentation on this. Is it a new partition scheme (e.g., MBR, GPT, APM, Tegra PT, MTD's command line partition table parsing, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

JSON files with .bpt extensions are consumed by bpttool - A tool for partitioning disk images for Brillo and Android.

This is open sourced and is hosted at **https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/tools/bpt/+/master/**

Partitioning directives are expressed in the .bpt JSON file.

Looking at the history of the repository (relatively new, only 4 months old). This was first introduced for Brillo and will probably end up in Android versions soon (In Nougat perhaps?). This may be a replacement for the GPT partitioning scheme or a derivative of it.